# Does ansible support encryption of s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, ansible

I am unable to create an encrypted s3 bucket using ansible with following error:

> fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"attempts": 5, "changed":
>   false, "failed_when_result": true, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for
>   (s3_bucket) module: encrypt, kms_key_id Supported parameters include:
>   aws_access_key, aws_secret_key, ceph, ec2_url, force, name, policy,
>   profile, region, requester_pays, s3_url, security_token, state, tags,
>   validate_certs, versioning"}

I am using ansible 2.5.7 , python 2.7.5

Answer (score 0):

As both [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/s3_bucket_module.html) and the error message you posted very clearly state, the `s3_bucket` module does NOT support any parameters called `encrypt` or `kms_key_id`.

However, there is an [`aws_s3` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/aws_s3_module.html), which DO support those parameters. Using the `aws_s3` module you should be able to achieve what you want.